# Lightning-combobox dropdown options not visible on UI

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

Dropdown options for the lightning combobox are not getting displayed on UI.
All values are getting fetched through the standard method getPicklistValuesByRecordType in the Js file of LWC component.

kindly assist me, where and what did I miss in the below snippet:
Code for the the UI
LWC htmlfile

```
<lightning-tabset class="slds-tabs_small">
<template for:each={tabList} for:item="tab">
<lightning-tab label={tab.label} key={tab.Index} value={tab.Index} style="margin: 0.5rem;">

<lightning-combobox
label="Field"
options={options} 
required="true">
</lightning-combobox>
</lightning-tab>
</template>
</lightning-tabset>
```

Handling to display the picklist field values
JS file

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
export default class Test extends LightningElement {
@track tabList = [];
connectedCallback()
{
    console.log('inside getTabs');  
    this.tabList.push(
{
        Index: 0,
        label: 1 + 'Tab',
        TabName: '1st Tab',
        TabNo:1+'st Tab',
     },
{
        Index: 1,
        label: 2 + 'Tab',
        TabName: '2nd Tab',
        TabNo:2+'nd Tab',
       
     },
)
}

@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: TURBODISP_OBJECT, recordTypeId:'recordtypIdPassedhere' }) 
fetchPicklist({error,data})
{

if(data && data.picklistFieldValues)
{
    data.picklistFieldValues["Field1__c"].values.forEach(optionData => {
       this.options.push({label : optionData.label, value : optionData.value});
   }); 

  console.log('values[]'+ JSON.stringify(this.options));
}
}
}
```

Expecting dropdown values on UI

Comment: It seems you are using picklist values of a single field, have you tried using [getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values) instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Dropdown options for the lightning combobox are not getting displayed on UI.

I think there are following things missing in your LWC's JS File:

1. Import of object schema which you are referencing in this property : TURBODISP_OBJECT.
2. Declaring options property.

**Please try following code snippet in the JS file:**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import TURBODISP_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/<object_api_name>'; //1. change(missing)

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    @track tabList = [];
    options; //2. change(missing)
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('inside getTabs');
        this.tabList.push(
            {
                Index: 0,
                label: 1 + 'Tab',
                TabName: '1st Tab',
                TabNo: 1 + 'st Tab',
            },
            {
                Index: 1,
                label: 2 + 'Tab',
                TabName: '2nd Tab',
                TabNo: 2 + 'nd Tab',

            },
        )
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: TURBODISP_OBJECT, recordTypeId: 'recordtypIdPassedhere' })
    fetchPicklist({ error, data }) {

        if (data && data.picklistFieldValues) {
            this.options = new Array(); //Addition
            data.picklistFieldValues["Stream_Opted__c"].values.forEach(optionData => {
                this.options.push({ label: optionData.label, value: optionData.value });
            });
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options)));
        }
    }
}
```